# Gnome 3 detects my screen differently VGA/HDMI

Tags: linux, resolution, hdmi, vga, gnome3

I have a screen that is correctly detected by gnome in VGA, he said the screen made 40 ", but when I connect HDMI, he said the screen made 7".

Can I configure this option?

Comment: It’s not unusual for a screen to present different EDID blobs on different connectors. Sounds like one of those is erroneous. Are you experiencing any issues with that?